# OmniSharp IntelliSense doesn't work in Visual Studio Code (Unity)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I was trying to set up VS Code to work with Unity for IntelliSense. I followed the instructions but OmniSharp seems to be misbehaving.

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 1/21/2023, 4:57:42 PM     Target: c:\Users\user\Unity Projects\Kinda Better Minecraft\Kinda Better Minecraft.sln  OmniSharp server started.     Path: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.2-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.2\OmniSharp.exe     PID: 7388  [STDERR] 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  [ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

IntelliSense doesn't work. I could type yifrujniut; and it wouldn't see anything wrong.

I'm on windows if that helps.

I was expecting IntelliSense to work. I tried reinstalling VS Code, reinstalling the .NET SDK but I had no idea what was causing the issue.

Comment: The error message says, 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.” The `cmd` app should be `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`, and `C:\WINDOWS\system32` ought to be in your PATH. Could your anti-virus software be protecting you from OmniSharp?

Comment: @padeso I don't have an antivirus. do i try turning off windows defender?

Comment: I’d consider Windows Defender to be antivirus, but I doubt it’s the problem. The point is that OmniSharp appears to be having trouble finding `cmd,` which is a pretty basic Windows executable. Your system must have some unexpected configuration detail — like `C:\WINDOWS\system32` is not in your PATH for some reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out, you're right. It wasn't in my Path